# How to get current locale of my environment?

Tags: c++, c, locale

Had tried following code in Linux, but always return 'C' under different `LANG` settings.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
#include <locale>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"locale 1: "<<setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL)<<endl;
    cout<<"locale 2: "<<setlocale(LC_CTYPE, NULL)<<endl;

    locale l;
    cout<<"locale 3: "<<l.name()<<endl;
}

$ ./a.out
locale 1: C
locale 2: C
locale 3: C
$
$ export LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8
$ ./a.out
locale 1: C
locale 2: C
locale 3: C
```

What should I do to get current locale setting in Linux(like Ubuntu)?

Another question is, is it the same way to get locale in Windows?

Comment: In C and C++ the locale always starts out as the "C" locale. You have to specifically ask for the program's locale to be changed to the environment's locale.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

From `man 3 setlocale` (New maxim: "When in doubt, read the entire manpage."):

> If locale is `""`, each part of the locale that should be modified is set according to the environment variables.

So, we can read the environment variables by calling `setlocale` at the beginning of the program, as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    cout << "LC_ALL: " << setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL) << endl;
    cout << "LC_CTYPE: " << setlocale(LC_CTYPE, NULL) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My system does not support the `zh_CN` locale, as the following output reveals:

```
$ ./a.out 
LC_ALL: en_US.utf8
LC_CTYPE: en_US.utf8
$ export LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8
$ ./a.out 
LC_ALL: C
LC_CTYPE: C
```

**Windows:** I have no idea about Windows locales.  I suggest starting with an [MSDN search](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=locale&ac=8), and then opening a *separate* Stack Overflow question if you still have questions.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a C++ version of getting current locale? I assume it should be in `<locale>` but have no idea how to use it.

Comment: @Deqing: I have no idea.  Search for documentation.  https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+locale

Comment: Note that Windows systems will often return `English_United States` instead of `en-US` and possibly with the code page appended, usually `English_United States.1252`.

Comment: For windows there is also a function strftime_l which takes a private local object without changing the global locale: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strftime-wcsftime-strftime-l-wcsftime-l?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 27):

Just figured out how to get locale by C++, simply use an empty string "" to construct std::locale, which does the same thing as setlocale(LC_ALL, "").

```
locale l("");
cout<<"Locale by C++: "<<l.name()<<endl;
```

This [link](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibug/24-3.html) described differences in details between C locale and C++ locale.

Comment: setlocale(LC_ALL, "") sets system default local. Use setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL) to get the current locale

Comment: Now, it outputs empty string.

Answer (score 5):

For Windows use the following code:

```
LCID lcid = GetThreadLocale();
wchar_t name[LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH];
if (LCIDToLocaleName(lcid, name, LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH, 0) == 0)
    error(GetLastError());
std::wcout << L"Locale name = " << name << std::endl;
```

This is going to print something like "en-US".

To purge sublanguage information use the following:

```
wchar_t parentLocateName[LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH];
if (GetLocaleInfoEx(name, LOCALE_SPARENT, parentLocateName, LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH) == 0)
    error(GetLastError());
std::wcout << L"parentLocateName = " << parentLocateName << std::endl;
```

This will give you just "en".

Answer (score 3):

A good alternative to consider instead of std::locale is boost::locale which is capable of returning more reliable information - see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/locale/doc/html/locale_information.html

boost::locale::info has the following member functions:

```
std::string name() -- the full name of the locale, for example en_US.UTF-8
std::string language() -- the ISO-639 language code of the current locale, for example "en".
std::string country() -- the ISO-3199 country code of the current locale, for example "US".
std::string variant() -- the variant of current locale, for example "euro".
std::string encoding() -- the encoding used for char based strings, for example "UTF-8"
bool utf8() -- a fast way to check whether the encoding is UTF-8.
```

Comment: is boost cross platform?

Comment: My use case is just to provide correctly encoded strings (and boost is already part of the project), so this is a neat way to figure out the required target encoding.

Answer (score 2):

The [default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/locale) of `std::locale` creates a copy of the global C++ locale.

So to get the name of the current locale:

```
std::cout << std::locale().name() << '\n';
```

Comment: That returns the global locale whose name is usually "C" and hence not very useful.  
  
As others have said, you want `locale("")` not `locale()`  
  
  
See  
https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/locale/name/ and  
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/name