# How to check if console/font supports Unicode?

Tags: c++, c++11, unicode, compatibility

I'm currently programming a little card game in C++, and I would like to use the Unicode characters for the card symbols, but I also wish to support consoles that can't display them.

Is there any way to check if the console and font can display certain Unicode characters without asking the user ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170488/how-to-get-current-locale-of-my-environment should be of interest. I'm not sure the locale identifiers are standardized though, better keep a togglable option at hand too.

Comment: The console specifics are OS dependent.  On which OS are you develpping ?