# How to get the locale of the current user in OSX using C++

Tags: c++, macos

I have a C++ application where I need to retrieve the locale of the current user. How can I do it with OSX Yosemite and newer?

I've tried something like `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, NULL);` but it just returns `UTF-8` where my system is clearly in Spanish (es_AR)

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170488/how-to-get-current-locale-of-my-environment)?

Comment: I just tried, but it does not work with OSX. My code:  setlocale(LC_ALL, ""); setlocale(LC_CTYPE, NULL); and the result is UTF-8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some try and error and lot of help from internet and other questions I did it.

If I want to get only the language.

```
CFLocaleRef cflocale = CFLocaleCopyCurrent();
auto value = (CFStringRef)CFLocaleGetValue(cflocale, kCFLocaleLanguageCode);    
std::string str(CFStringGetCStringPtr(value, kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
CFRelease(cflocale);
```

This way, at str I'll get a std::string with the language. If I need something else, I can replace `kCFLocaleLanguageCode` with any other constant from `CFLocale`

Also I needed the header `#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>`